# Sencha Touch 2: Message box with buttons: How to align buttons vertically?

Tags: javascript, css, popup, sencha-touch-2, messagebox

Here is the code that works fine.

```
Ext.Msg.show({
    title: 'The title',
    message: 'and some text...',
    scope: this,
    buttons : [
       {
         itemId : 'no',
         text   : 'Top button'
       },
       {
           itemId : 'yes',
           text   : 'Bottom button'
         }
       ],
    fn: function(btn) {
      if (btn == 'yes'){
       //do something
      }
     }
});
```

How to align the buttons vertically? By default they go in one line horizontally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have two buttons in your `Ext.Msg.Show`, you can achieve the desired results with '**docked**' property. (Like this):

Good Luck!

Here is the updated code:

```
Ext.Msg.show({

    title: 'The title',
    message: 'and some text...',

    scope: this,
    buttons : [

       {

         docked: 'top',
         itemId : 'no',
           id: 'no',
         text   : 'Top button'
       },
       {

           docked: 'bottom',
           itemId : 'yes',
           id : 'yes',
           text   : 'Bottom button'
         }
       ],
    fn: function(btn) {
      if (btn == 'yes'){
       //do something
      }
     }
});
```

Comment: I was going to write "You've made my day, thank you!", but after adding docked as you recommended, now I see 4 buttons instead of two when this message shows again, on 3rd display I see 6 buttons. That doesn't happen without docked property. Is there any chance to fix it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Set an ID for both the buttons.. The beauty is that 'id' is unique. Hence, it doesn't let itself create a duplicate.. :) See my updated answer..

Comment: You are right, but... Sorry, now there are ALWAYS two buttons (not 4,6,8) on this popup. That's what I want. But, unfortunately, these buttons appear on another popups with another logic. I think the option is to assign the same ids on another popups as well, but sometimes there is only one button in the popup, not two. Any more ideas? I really appreciate your help. Thank you again.

Comment: Geeniewanted, I made a separate extension of a view. The whole view contains only:
Ext.define('WildFlower.view.MyMessageBox', {
    extend: 'Ext.MessageBox',
});

That helped me. 
Geeniewanted, thank you very much for your ideas. Now I know the tricks with ids :)  Thank you!

Comment: @GenieWanted What if there more than 2 buttons, how to align them vertically? any ideas? I am running exactly the same case.